# How can I achieve replicability with the latest version of TensorFlow while doing grid search for tuning?

Tags: tensorflow, grid-search, replicate

With latest version of tensorflow, I do not get replicable results.

This was not a problem with older version I was running. However, when I upgraded to latest version, I lost replicability.

Given this, I am missing how to do tuning. I get different "best parameters" with each run.

I have seeds set to constant and no GPUs.

Is there something I should be doing differently to tune with this latest version?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by setting the **Global Random Seed** as mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/set_seed)

> Operations that rely on a random seed actually derive it from two
> seeds: the global and operation-level seeds. This sets the global
> seed.

To set all the seeds at once, which includes setting the seeds for Python, Numpy and Tensorflow together, use :

```
tf.keras.utils.set_random_seed(seed)
```

The above code is equivalent to the following :

```
import random
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
random.seed(seed)
np.random.seed(seed)
tf.random.set_seed(seed)
```